# SQL Server: join rows into one line without subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Declarations table

```
| id |
+----+
| 1  |
| 2  |
```

Conflicts table

```
| declarationId | title  |
+---------------+--------+
| 1             | qqq    |
| 1             | wwww   |
| 2             | ttttt  |
```

Query with subquery

```sql
SELECT 
    dd.[Id],
    (SELECT ',' + Title 
     FROM [dbo].[Conflicts] cc 
     WHERE cc.DeclarationId = dd.Id 
     FOR XML PATH(''))
FROM 
    [dbo].[Declarations] dd
```

Result

```
| 1  | ,qqq,wwww, |
| 2  | ,ttttt,    |
```

How to achieve same result without a subquery?

I want to create view with fulltext index, but it is not possible to create index on views with subqueries.

Comment: Write a user-defined function to implement the `string_agg()` functionality provided in SQL Server 2017.

Comment: Would a GROUP BY Conflicts.DeclarationId with GROUP_CONCAT avoid the subquery?

Comment: @Fry GROUP_CONCAT isn't available in SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this in SQL Server 2012 without a sub-query, although as Gordon pointed out, you can hide the subquery in a user-defined function.   However, I suspect that doing so will not serve your purpose of being able to create a view with fulltext index, so I think you will need to find another way of doing what you want, whatever that may be.

Answer (score 0):

```
 WITH CTE_TableName AS 
 (
    SELECT DeclarationId, Title
      FROM Conflicts 
  )
 SELECT t0.DeclarationId
        ,STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + t1.Title
          FROM CTE_TableName t1
         WHERE t1.DeclarationId = t0.DeclarationId
        ORDER BY t1.Title
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, LEN(','), '') AS Titles
  FROM CTE_TableName t0
 GROUP BY t0.DeclarationId
 ORDER BY DeclarationId;
```

Comment: That's a sub-query inside your STUFF function.

Answer (score 0):

The best option to create a join or select without using a subquery is to create a user defined function as pointed out earlier.

Create a user defined function as below:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION AppendString()
RETURNS varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @temp VARCHAR(50);

    SELECT @temp = ',' + Title 
    FROM [dbo].[Conflicts] cc 
    WHERE cc.DeclarationId = dd.Id 
    FOR XML PATH('')

    RETURN @temp
END
GO
```

Then use the function in your join statement

```
SELECT 
    dd.Id, AppendString AS Title 
FROM 
    Declarations DD
INNER JOIN 
    Conflicts CC ON DD.Id = CC.declarationId
```

Comment: First of all, you're not **assigning** the `@temp` variable inside your function - ever - so this is always going to return `NULL`. And secondly, when calling a function in a `SELECT` you need to prefix it with the schema and have parenthesis to indicate a **function** - like this: `SELECT dbo.AppendString()`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I forgot to assign my selected value to my temp variable. Edited my answer.

Comment: OK - but my second point is still true: you **must** use the schema prefix when calling a function, **AND** you **must** use the empty parenthesis to indicate that it's a fuction : `SELECT dbo.AppendString() AS Title ....`